# How to remove bottom and right box shadow on submit button?

Tags: html, css

I have done a lot of researching on this topic and couldn't find the right answer.

I have an input button that I want to have a grey border with a white background. But when I set the background to white, it automatically creates a shadow like border on the bottom and right of the button. I can't seem a way to remove it. Below is the css code and the HTML

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

**CSS:**

```
  input{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 380px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="sign_in"  type="submit" value="Sign In">
```

Comment: try adding `box-shadow: none;` to the input

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the default gradient of the button? If so, just add the rules `outline: 0;` and `border:1px solid grey;` and it won't render the shadow like border.

Comment: @JCOC611: why don't you add it as answer?

Comment: @naveen just making sure that's what the OP meant

Comment: @JCOC611 has it right: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/noqjvv1h/

Comment: @JCOC611. Thanks a lot!!!! That worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

You said you want a grey border around your button but you haven't applied it in your css.

Update your css:

```
input{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 380px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;  /*Add your border property*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers add retro borders once you change the background color of a button. Fixing it is as simple as adding the following rules:

```
outline: 0;
border: 1px solid grey;
```